# Get the average of the last group in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays of matching data. One with the values and the other with the time. I round time to the nearest 5 minutes and in result I have a new array with hours that repeat themself es. I group the equal hours, count them, summerize their respective values in the other array and take an average for that hour. here is the code:

```
$first_hour = array('11:01', '12:04', '13:00', '15:28', "15:43", "15:53", "15:55", "16:02", "16:05", "16:17", "16:15", "16:21", "16:25", "16:33", "16:35", "16:43", "16:45", "16:56", "16:58", "17:00", "17:04", "17:07", "17:19");
$values = array(12, 23, 5, 90, 12, 23, 45, 56, 12, 15, 43, 48, 54, 62, 52, 41, 74, 54, 84, 75, 96, 69, 36);
$minutes = 5;
$precision = 60 * $minutes;
$time = "00:00";
$average = 0;


//round first array to nearest 5 minutes
$timestamp = strtotime($first_hour);
$data_ora = date("H,i", round($timestamp / $precision) * $precision);

//the hours array will become like this:
$first_hour = array('11:00', '12:05', '13:00', '15:30', "15:45", "15:50", "15:55", "16:00", "16:05", "16:15", "16:15", "16:20", "16:25", "16:35", "16:35", "16:45", "16:45", "17:00", "17:00", "17:00", "17:05", "17:10", "17:20");
if ($first_hour == $time) {
    if ($values[$i] > 0) {
        $indexi = $indexi + 1;
        $total = $total + $values;
 echo "</br> total = ".$total;
        $i++;
    } else {
        $time = date("H,i", round($timestamp / $precision) * $precision);
        //echo "time has changed";

           $average = $total / $index;

        $dataora = date("Y,m,d", round($timestamp)) . "," . $time;

        //fill in the vectors   
        $v[1] = $average;
        $v[2] = $dataora;
        echo "</br> average = " . $v[1];

        $indexi = 0;
        $totali = 0;
    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
"total = 2996
 total = 3325
 total = 3656
 total = 3996
 average = 333
 total = 329
 total = 652
 total = 976
 total = 1304
 total = 1630
 total = 1961
 total = 2297
 total = 2629
 average = 328.625
 total = 332
 total = 660
 total = 997
 total = 1320
 total = 1646
 total = 1967
```

For each group there is an average calculated, except for the last group of values. How can I calculate its average? For the last group it gets into the first condition but it doesn't take a break (change hour) to fall into the `else` so that the average is calculated.

Comment: this output is of the actual code, the one provided above is a similar one, but with less data, for testing purposes!

Comment: Where is echo "total" in your code?

Comment: @sємsєм it's in the second 'if' condition. I just edited the code.. sorry i skipped that

Comment: Using `continue` may be a shortcut, but it counts toward a messy code here. Maybe it's worth redefining the problem to keep it simple with an actual looping architecture.

Comment: $index is not defined.

Comment: Even with different data, there is no way that code could possibly produce that output. Even allowing for all the undefined variables which I'm assuming you've defined elsewhere, you've got arrays compared with strings and arrays added to integers which couldn't possibly work. Could you please update your question with a code sample that will actually run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain the sample code you have provided doesn't match your real code, so I'm not going to try and fix that, but I will try and explain how you might fix the problem you claim to have in your real code.

Assumedly you have a loop of some sort that is iterating over the values in the `$values` array. I also assume that some of the values in that array are less than or equal to zero, and those are the points at which you display the average.

Your problem then is that your loop reaches the end of the array without having a chance to display the average for the last set of values.

One easy solution, is to add a zero to the end of the array if there isn't already one there. That way the last value the loop encounters will always be a zero, which will match the condition needed to display an average.

If that is not feasible, you could make your loop not stop when it reaches the end of the array, so if it's a while loop, it essentially becomes:

```
while (true) ...
```

Then you change your first condition to this:

```
if ($i < count($values) && $values[$i] > 0) {
```

so it only matches if you haven't gone past the end of the array. Otherwise it falls through to displaying the average.

And at the end of the average code, you add another check to to see if you're past the end of the array and break out of the loop.

```
if ($i >= count($values)) break;
```

These changes alone won't fix the sample code you've provided, but it might help if your real code matches the functionality you've described in the question.